# PHP OAuthProvider Invalid Signature when passing additional $_GET params

Tags: php, oauth

I am creating an OAuth provider and it currently works, except when I pass additional $_GET parameters for filters, etc - I am using the Authorization header approach.

When I pass a URL like /me/actions it works - however, if I pass a URL like /me/actions?status=pending it breaks saying invalid signature.

I guess part of my problem is that I don't understand all of what params I should expect the OAuthProvider library to parse. Is it trying to parse additional $_GET params or simply ignoring them? Since it works without hte $_GET params is there a likely culprit?

Answer (score 1):

Hope its not to late. Are you using PECL's OAuth & OAuthProvider classes? If so, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.setparam.php) method.

Using, on the server, the following:

```
$provider->setParam("status", NULL); //$provider = your instance of OAuthProvider
```

you're telling the provider to ignore those parameters when validating the signature. Do this for each parameter you send.

Hope it helps!